# Inconvertible types error in java

Tags: java, casting

I have the following code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Excercise613 {
    /** 
      *  Display the prompt to the user; wait for the user to enter
      *  a whole number; return it.  
      */            

    public static int askInt(String prompt) {    
        String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(prompt);
        Double d = Double.parseDouble(s);
        return d >= 0 ? (int) d : (int) (d - 1);
    } // End of method
} // End of class
```

When I compile this, I get an error at the bottom of the screen that says "inconvertible types.
     required: int; found: java.lang.Double" And then it highlights the "(int) d" piece of code.

What am I doing wrong here? Why isn't the type casting working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the doubleValue() function.

For example:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Excercise613 {
    // Display the prompt to the user; wait for the user to enter a whole number; 
    // return it.  
    public static int askInt(String prompt) {    
        String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(prompt);
        Double d = Double.parseDouble(s);                     
        return d >= 0 ? (int) d.doubleValue() : (int) (d.doubleValue() - 1);
    } // End of method
} // End of class
```

Or you can remove the `(int)` casts and just call `d.intValue()`. For example:
`return d >= 0 ? d.intValue() : (d.intValue() - 1);`

Comment: That worked; the code compiles now. But why is it necessary for me to add this? I've written code before where simply having the variable was enough to cast it. @DermotBlair

Comment: Double with a capital 'D' is a boxed primitive and cannot be cast to an primitive int using `(int)` but the primitive double with a small 'd' can be cast to an int. Therefore to cast a Double to an int, you need to get it's double value using the doubleValue() function.

Comment: If this worked for you and you are happy with my explanation, could you please accept the answer using the tick button. Thanks. If you have any more questions regarding this, just let me know.